# What value does my "out IDbConnection parameter" need?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have a method where one of the parameters is "out IDbConnection parameter". I tried filling it with a variable that implements System.Data.IDbConnection, but it is still erring out on the build. What do I need to pass to this parameter, and how is the IDbConnection parameter used?

Comment: Please post details of the error and the failing code

Comment: An out parameter gives you a value, you don't need to provide one. You do need to repeat the `out` keyword. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're missing the out keyword in front of the parameter in the calling method. You could simply do this:

```
using (var dbConnection = myObject.Method(out IDbConnection myConnection)
{...}
```

The System.Data.IDbConnection interface implements IDisposable and has a Close method. The method you are calling probably creates a connection to the database and assigns it to the variable that you passed in ("myConnection" seen above).

The out keyword not only allows the method to initialize that variable from within the method, but it allows you to use that variable outside of the method and continue working with that connection or dispose of it with the using statement as seen above.

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: Oops. I see that I was initializing the variable before the method and forgetting the out keyword. Thanks for the example and the explanation!